# Linked-List and Double Pointer in C

Tags: c, linked-list, double-pointer

so I'm trying to build a linked list in a function that takes in a double pointer to an originally empty linked list. I manage to add in the first element successfully but when I try to add more nodes (under the conditions of the while loop), it doesn't seem to work. When I try to iterate the list after elements have been added, it only appears to have to first element in, even though it entered the while loop.

Also, I am uncertain of the correct what to link the entries to the parameter passed list.

(Ignore the parts that don't have anything to do with the list.)

```
void parse_varseq(Variable **vars)
{
   DBG_start("<varseq>");
    
    char *var_id;
    ValType v_type;
    Variable *v;
    expect_id(&var_id);
    
    v = (Variable *) malloc(sizeof(Variable)*1);
    v->id = var_id;
    v->pos = position;
    v->next = NULL;
     
    
    while (token.type == TOK_COMMA) {
        get_token(&token);
        expect_id(&var_id);

         //add next item to linked-list
         v->next = (Variable *) malloc(sizeof(Variable)*1);
         v->next->id = var_id;
         v->next->pos = position;
         v->next->next = NULL; 
    }

    expect(TOK_AS);
    parse_type(&v_type);
    IDprop *init_prop;
    
    //set return type for each item
    while (v->next != NULL) {
        v->type = return_type;
        v = v->next;
        
       }

    *vars = v;
    
    DBG_end("</varseq>");
}
```

Comment: You are not updating the 'v' in the loop. It always points to the head.

Comment: So how would I go about updating it? Creating a temporary node?

Comment: First, store the head (v) to a temp node, in order to prevent the losing the head reference. Then update the 'v' in the loop by v = v->next. Keeping a tail node is a good solution also.

Comment: I've done this so far: Variable *temp = v;
         v = v->next;
         v = (Variable *) malloc(sizeof(Variable)*1);
         v->id = var_id;
         v->pos = position;
         v->next = NULL;
         v = temp;    but it doesn't seem to work, where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't like the expression "doulbe pointer" if one is unfamiliar with these concepts it's an easy way to further confuse, "pointer to pointer" is much clearer.